# Multiple mod_rewrite parameters for same php file

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I want

`site.com/home/profile`

to map to

`site.com/index.php?view=home&type=profile`

and

`site.com/profile/a1b2c3`

to map to

`site.com/index.php?view=profile&id=a1b2c3`

and

`site.com/profile/friends`

should map to

`site.com/index.php?view=profile&type=friends`

as well as (this already works, just including it for semantics)

`site.com/profile` OR
`site.com/home`

to map to

`site.com/index.php?view=profile` OR
`site.com/index.php?view=home`

Here is my `.htaccess` file located in `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?view=$1&type=$2 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png|bmp|svg|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?view=$1&id=$2 [QSA]

## This part already works, but will it interfere with my above rules?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?view=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

What am I doing wrong? This only works for one or the other, but not both!

Comment: The obvious thing is that your PHP application should be handling request routing, like most other PHP applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?view=$1&type=$2 [QSA]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png|bmp|svg|ico)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?view=$1&id=$2 [QSA]
> ```

You have the same `RewriteRule` pattern for both rules. So the first will naturally capture all requests. (Although you are missing an `L` flag, so processing continues...)

It looks like `/profile/...` is a special case of the more general rewrite? So, you can specifically check for `profile` in the first path segment. (Although the fact that you are not doing this leads me to think there is something more to this question?) This will also need to go first, before the more generic catch-all rewrite. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(profile)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?view=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?view=$1&type=$2 [QSA,L]
```

If the check against `REQUEST_URI` is an attempt at optimisation (to avoid the filesystem check) then it's in the wrong place; it should be the first condition. However, you could make this a separate directive (if you have no other directives in your file). For example, *before* your existing directives:

```
RewriteRule \.(jpg|css|js|gif|png|bmp|svg|ico)$ - [L]
```

If the requested URL ends with any of the stated file extensions (regardless of whether it actually maps to an existing file) then processing stops.

**UPDATE:**

> Basically id contains an MD5 hash, type is a unique identifier which is always a word

An MD5 hash is a 32 char hexadecimal string - so you can check for this specifically to avoid conflicts with "types". For example, change the first `RewriteRule` to read:

```
RewriteRule ^(profile)/([a-f0-9]{32})/?$ /index.php?view=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

When pattern matching you should always be as specific as possible.

Comment: This almost works, except for when I have something like `/profile/friends` then it doesn't work. Where you have `RewriteRule ^(profile)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?view=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]`, it should also take in consideration when the parameter is `id` OR `type` too ... how can we edit this for this case?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, how is `/profile/friends` different from `/profile/a1b2c3`? Should `/profile/friends` not rewrite to `/index.php?view=profile&id=friends`? How can this be determined? "it should also take in consideration when the parameter isnt id but type too" - not sure what you mean. Bear in mind that in `.htaccess` you only have the requested URL from which to get this information. Are the number of "types" limited for instance?

Comment: `/profile/friends` should rewrite to `index.php?view=profile&type=friends` but `/profile/a1b2c3` should rewrite to `index.php?view=profile&id=a1b2c3` ... how can we edit the solution to make this possible?

Comment: But how do you differentiate "friends" and "a1b2c3"? I'm assuming the `id` "a1b2c3" is infinitely variable ("e8ujakw", "hstrqwgh", etc...), or are you wanting to match this literally? Or do id's always contain digits or are always 6 characters long? Or is the literal string "friends" another "special case"?

Comment: `id` is an alphanumeric identifier (yes, infinitely variable) for a given user, and `type` is the route we are navigating to from the current page. `friends` belongs to the `type` variable and `a1b2c3` belongs to the `id` variable. Is it possible to add a rewrite rule for these multiple cases?

Comment: But, how do you differentiate the two values? "friends" also satisfies the condition of being _alphanumeric_. Or do id's _always_ contain at least 1 digit?

Comment: Basically `id` contains an MD5 hash, `type` is a unique identifier which is always a word.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: I reviewed your update, and its causing a small issue in my web server for images. I have my css/js files in `/libs/css/` or `/libs/js/` however, the new rules are adding `profile` as the base directory so the server tries to look for `/profile/libs/css/`, but this directory doesn't exist so it returns 404. How to add the exception to exclude adding it for css/js files?

Comment: Your missing CSS/JS files are really a different problem. This is probably because you are using relative URLs to your CSS/JS files. This is a client-side HTML issue, not something that can be resolved in `.htaccess`. See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css